# How to extract data using odoo python api?

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-11

I am currently running odoo 11 and want to extract the data using its python API so I can transfer it to AWS database. I have the API but not sure about the code.

Comment: I can help you but I need more information. If I resume , you want get data from Odoo by the xml_rpc API and inject it in AWS DB. It's possible but. How do you want to do this ? By a python script ? explain all your process. In this fact I can only give you this URL. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html

Comment: @ jo541 thanks for commenting. I would like to set up a data warehouse on AWS using python.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

### Out Odoo

If you don't have access to Odoo and cannot add module. You can inject data from external script to you AWS DB with Odoo API.

Step

---

1. Create a python file
2. In the python file write code to fetch data from Odoo (More information in documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/webservices/odoo.html)
3. With data formatted. Inject data in your AWS DB.
4. Add script on server.
5. Create a linux cron (If you used linux server).

### In Odoo

If you have access to Odoo and can add module. You can inject data from Odoo to you AWS DB.

Step

---

1. Create a module.
2. Create a cron to be executed regularly.
3. A model with function to connect to your AWS DB and inject data.
4. Instal module on your Odoo.